# Matlab - Nested for loop doesn't run till end

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nested-loops

I want to multiply the returns and the expected returns for each firm for the respective earnings date, e.g. Return(30-Jan-2017)*Return(31-Jan-2017)*Return(01-Feb-2017) [the same for the next earnings date and so on]

[image: see pic1]

My Code is as follows:

```
firms = unique(T.Ticker(:,:))
for i = 1:length(firms)
    idx = firms(i);
    Dates = T.EarningsDate(T.Ticker == idx,:);
    ERDates=unique(Dates);
    for n = 1:length(ERDates)
        x = strcmpi(Dates,ERDates(n));
        T.ret(x) = prod(T.Return(x))
    end
end
```

However I get all the correct calculated values for APPL (the first 60 rows) but then the loop stops somehow and I only receive 0.

[image: see pic2]

Does anybody has some hint, what I can do?

Comment: It is hard to know what `T` is. I’m guessing a `table` object? Take a look at each of your intermediate variables, and ensure yourself that they contain the values you expect. Running your code in the debugger is the ideal way to do so. You’re probably mixing up indices, causing you to rewrite the data in the top rows multiple times, and not write in the bottom rows at all.

Comment: The variable `Dates` is only of length 60. So when you do `x = strcmpi(Dates,ERDates(n));` you get a logical vector with only 60 elements, which is why you keep overwriting the first  60 rows. Do as Cris Luengo said, I am sure you will find out the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame change: you don't need to use a nested loop if you use `findgroups` to identify the unique groupings by Ticker and EarningsDate, then just do a single loop over these.

First, a minimal example data set:

```
% Set up some example data
T = table();
rng(0);
T.Ticker = repelem( ["AAPL"; "AMGN"], 6, 1 );
T.EarningsDate = repelem( datetime(2022, randi(12,4,1), randi(28,4,1)), 3, 1 );
T.Date = T.EarningsDate + repmat( [-1;0;1], 4, 1 );
T.Return = rand(height(T),1)-0.5;
T.ExpectedReturn = T.Return .* rand(height(T),1)*2;
```

Then a simple loop, see comments for details:

```
% Get groups for each unique combination of Ticker and EarningsDate
grp = findgroups( T.Ticker, T.EarningsDate );
% Loop over the groups and get the product for each one
T.ret(:) = NaN;
for igrp = 1:max(grp)
    idx = (grp == igrp); % Rows which match this group
    % Assign all group rows a "ret" value equal to their "Return" product
    T.ret( idx ) = prod( T.Return(idx) ); 
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Learned again how simple it can go